# select from tables with different numbers of rows

Tags: mysql, select, join, union

I'm hoping there is a simple answer to this. Competitors race over a series of 3 races. Some competitors only show up for one race. How could I show a final result for ALL competitors?

race 1

```
+------+--------+
| name | result |
+------+--------+
| Ali  |     30 |
| Bob  |     28 |
| Cal  |     26 |
+------+--------+
```

race 2

```
+------+--------+
| name | result |
+------+--------+
| Ali  |     32 |
| Bob  |     31 |
| Dan  |     24 |
+------+--------+
```

race 3

```
+------+--------+
| name | result |
+------+--------+
| Eva  |     23 |
| Dan  |     25 |
+------+--------+
```

The final result should look like this:

```
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| name | result | result | result |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
| Ali  |     30 |     32 |        |
| Bob  |     28 |     31 |        |
| Cal  |     26 |        |        |
| Dan  |        |     24 |     25 |
| Eva  |        |        |     23 |
+------+--------+--------+--------+
```

The problem I have is with ordering by name from multiple tables.

Here is the example data:

```
CREATE TABLE race (name varchar(20), result int);
CREATE TABLE race1 LIKE race;
INSERT INTO race1 VALUES ('Ali', '30'), ('Bob', '28'), ('Cal', '26');
CREATE TABLE race2 like race;
insert INTO race2 VALUES ('Ali', '32'), ('Bob', '31'), ('Dan', '24');
CREATE TABLE race3 LIKE race;
INSERT INTO race3 VALUES ('Eva', '23'), ('Dan', '25');
```

Many thanks!

Comment: I'd recommend putting all races in 1 table.

    `CREATE TABLE race (name varchar(20), race_id, result int);`

This should make it a lot easier to query. Especially if you want to add more races later.

Comment: I tried that but couldn't come up with a query that didn't involve a pivot to get the multiple rows per name into the right output format. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I created a new answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here we go !!!

```
select race1.name as name, race1.result, race2.result, race3.result from race1
    left join race2 on race2.name = race1.name 
    left join race3 on race3.name = race1.name

union

select race2.name as name, race1.result, race2.result, race3.result from race2
    left join race1 on race1.name = race2.name
    left join race3 on race3.name = race2.name

union

select race3.name as name, race1.result, race2.result, race3.result from race3
    left join race1 on race1.name = race3.name
    left join race2 on race2.name = race3.name;
```

It is working :)

Comment: Pulling the separate name columns together with AS is exactly the trick I needed. I thought they were just aliases but this shows that AS is clearly more functional than that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select s.name,
        max(case when s.R = 'Result1' then s.result else '' end) as result1,
        max(case when s.R = 'Result2' then s.result else '' end) as result2,
        max(case when s.R = 'Result3' then s.result else '' end) as result3
from
(
select 'Result1' as R,r1.* from race1 r1
union all
select 'Result2' as R,r2.* from race2 r2
union all
select 'Result3' as R,r3.* from race3 r3
) s
group by s.name
```

result

```
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| name | result1 | result2 | result3 |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
| Ali  | 30      | 32      |         |
| Bob  | 28      | 31      |         |
| Cal  | 26      |         |         |
| Dan  |         | 24      | 25      |
| Eva  |         |         | 23      |
+------+---------+---------+---------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: it seems like **Race1**, **Race2** and **Race3** are three different tables.

Answer (score 0):

I personally would create the schema in a different way.
One table for the users, one for the races and one that connects both:

```
-- Create syntax for TABLE 'races'
CREATE TABLE `races` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'users'
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

-- Create syntax for TABLE 'race_results'
CREATE TABLE `race_results` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `race_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `result` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Let's insert some data (should be equal to your data set).

```
-- Insert data
INSERT INTO users (name)values('Ali'),('Bob'),('Cal'),('Dan'), ('Eva');
INSERT INTO races (name)values('Race1'),('Race2'),('Race3');
INSERT INTO race_results (user_id, race_id, result)values(1,1,30),(2,1,30),(1,2,28),(2,2,31),(3,1,26),(4,2,24),(4,3,25),(5,3,23);
```

Then you could write the query like this:

```
-- Static version
SELECT us.name, sum(if(ra.name='Race1', result, null)) as Race1, sum(if(ra.name='Race2', result, null)) as Race2, sum(if(ra.name='Race3', result, null)) as Race3
FROM race_results as rr
LEFT JOIN users  as us on us.id = rr.user_id
LEFT JOIN races as ra on ra.id = rr.race_id
GROUP BY us.id;
```

Which gives you the result you're looking for. (I changed the column names to make it more obvious which result belongs to which race.)

But I've to admit that this works fine for 3 races but what if you have 30 or more?

Here is a more dynamic version of the above query, which kind of creates itself ;)

```
-- Dynamic version
SET @sql = '';
SELECT
    @sql := CONCAT(@sql,if(@sql='','',', '),temp.output)
FROM
    (SELECT
        CONCAT("sum(if(ra.name='", race.name, "', result, null)) as ", race.name) as output
    FROM races as race
) as temp;

SET @sql = CONCAT("SELECT us.name,", @sql, " FROM race_results as rr LEFT JOIN users  as us on us.id = rr.user_id LEFT JOIN races as ra on ra.id = rr.race_id GROUP BY 1;");
SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```